# Apply function struggle

Tags: r, dataframe, apply

I want to apply a function to every row in a data frame. I have a data frame with HW scores and I want to apply a function which drops the lowest score and calculates the average. Here are the functions involved

```
      # take the lowest score and drops it and then calculates average
      score_hw_d <- function(hw) {
      return (get_average(drop_lowest(hw)))
          }

     #drops lowest score
     drop_lowest <- function(x){
       x <- sort(x, decreasing = TRUE)
       x <- c(x[1:(length(x)-1)])
       x
        }
     # calculates average 

      get_average <- function(x,na.rm=TRUE) {if(mode(x) != 'numeric') 
      {stop("non-numeric argument")}
      if(na.rm==TRUE){
        x = remove_missing(x)}
       total <- 0
       for (n in 1:length(x)) {
        total= total  + x[n]

          }
         return(total/length(x))
         }
```

Here is the a snapshot dataset hws (many more rows

```
     new1  new2  new3  new4   new5  new6  new7  new8  new9
 1   100.0 100.0 100.0 100.0 100.00 100.0 100.0 100.0 100.0
  2    85.0  95.0 100.0  95.0  95.00  95.0 100.0 100.0 100.0
  3    87.5 100.0  85.0  70.0 100.00  98.0   0.0  80.0   0.0
  4    92.5 100.0 100.0 100.0  96.25  99.0 100.0  92.5  95.0
   5    32.5   0.0  65.0  60.0   0.00  46.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
  6    75.0  85.0  92.5  95.0 100.00  91.0   0.0   0.0  90.0
  7    90.0 100.0  97.5  95.0  80.00  80.0  52.0  90.0  90.0
  8    92.5  95.0 100.0  90.0 100.00  72.0  95.0  74.5 100.0
   9    82.5  85.0  92.5  70.0 100.00   0.0  84.0  90.0  95.0
```

## when I use

```
 data$homework <- apply(hws,1,score_hw_d)
```

I get a new columns with blank values, any help ?

Comment: `apply(hws, 1, function(r) { mean(sort(r)[-1]) })` will return the mean of each row, excluding the lowest value in each row. `sort` excludes missing values, so the mean will be calculated without missing values.

Comment: @nya's `which.min` approach is more than twice as fast as using `sort`, so go with that approach.

Comment: Please do not vandalise your posts. Once you have submitted a post, you have licensed the content to the Stack Overflow community at large (under the CC BY-SA license).

Answer (score 1):

The functionality can be achieved without the two custom functions:

```
hws = read.table(text="     new1  new2  new3  new4   new5  new6  new7  new8  new9
1   100.0 100.0 100.0 100.0 100.00 100.0 100.0 100.0 100.0
2    85.0  95.0 100.0  95.0  95.00  95.0 100.0 100.0 100.0
3    87.5 100.0  85.0  70.0 100.00  98.0   0.0  80.0   0.0
4    92.5 100.0 100.0 100.0  96.25  99.0 100.0  92.5  95.0
5    32.5   0.0  65.0  60.0   0.00  46.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
6    75.0  85.0  92.5  95.0 100.00  91.0   0.0   0.0  90.0
7    90.0 100.0  97.5  95.0  80.00  80.0  52.0  90.0  90.0
8    92.5  95.0 100.0  90.0 100.00  72.0  95.0  74.5 100.0
9    82.5  85.0  92.5  70.0 100.00   0.0  84.0  90.0  95.0")
apply(hws, 1, FUN=function(x) mean(x[-which.min(x)], na.rm=TRUE))
#        1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8         9 
#100.00000  97.50000  77.56250  97.84375  25.43750  78.56250  90.31250  93.37500  87.37500
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use any custom functions for this. It can be done using `tidyverse`

**load `tidyverse`**

```
library(tidyverse)
```

1. Take `hws` and define the student which we'll call the row number since we don't have names.
2. `gather` all of the test scores to change the dataset from wide to long.
3. `group` the dataframe by student
4. sort the dataframe by groups of students, and then in ascending order of their test scores (lowest first).
5. `slice` out the first score (which will be lowest).
6. `spread` the scores back into wide format.
7. `ungroup` the dataframe
8. add column that takes the `rowSums` for every row except the first (student) row. then divides it by the number of columns in the dataframe - 2. the minus 2 because of the student, and the dropped lowest score.

You'll now see that there are `NA`s for where the scores used to be. You could always leave it in long format, and you can still do `mean` calculations and everything else by specifying `na.rm = TRUE`.

```
hws2 <- hws %>%
  mutate(student = row_number()) %>%
  gather(test, score, contains("new")) %>%
  group_by(student) %>%
  arrange(student, score) %>%
  slice(-1) %>%
  spread(test, score) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(average = rowSums(.[,2:ncol(.)], na.rm = TRUE)/(ncol(.) - 2))
```

result:

```
> hws2
# A tibble: 9 x 11
  student  new1  new2  new3  new4   new5  new6  new7  new8  new9   average
    <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>
1       1    NA   100 100.0   100 100.00   100   100 100.0   100 100.00000
2       2    NA    95 100.0    95  95.00    95   100 100.0   100  97.50000
3       3  87.5   100  85.0    70 100.00    98    NA  80.0     0  77.56250
4       4    NA   100 100.0   100  96.25    99   100  92.5    95  97.84375
5       5  32.5    NA  65.0    60   0.00    46     0   0.0     0  25.43750
6       6  75.0    85  92.5    95 100.00    91    NA   0.0    90  78.56250
7       7  90.0   100  97.5    95  80.00    80    NA  90.0    90  90.31250
8       8  92.5    95 100.0    90 100.00    NA    95  74.5   100  93.37500
9       9  82.5    85  92.5    70 100.00    NA    84  90.0    95  87.37500
```

hope this works for your needs!